# Как сериализовать экземпляр класса в XML-строку?

Tags: c#, xml

Есть класс

```
class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

Я сериализую его прямо в XML-файл, используя XmlSerializer,

```
Point point = new Point();
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Point));
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"point.xml");

serializer.Serialize(writer, point);
writer.Close();
```

Как осуществить сериализацию не прямо в файл, а в строку (объект типа string)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `StreamWriter` надо использовать `StringWriter`:

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Point));
 using( StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(...) ) 
 {
     serializer.Serialize(writer,point);
     string serializedXML = writer.ToString();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Point1 point = new Point1();
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Point1));

    using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, point);

        stream.Position = 0;
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        label1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

public class Point1
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set;}
}
```